# Extremist influence in the management of Wikipedia

Tags: content-security-policy

(With the exception of blocked users) Why anyone who visits the wikipedia site can edit it!? I realized recently, Extremist people have infiltrated Wikipedia. As well as realized there was no way to report them. **Wikipedia does not have a centralised author or content reviewer**, and their content is maintained by volunteer editors

Comment: Anyone can edit it because that's the entire point of it - it's a repository of data created and collated by volunteers. This doesn't read like a question, but more like a rant about Wikipedia. Yes, extremists can edit it. So can ultra-moderates. So can anyone else with a computer. Similarly, anyone can ask and answer questions on Stack Exchange, and suggest edits.

Answer (score 7):

[This is a misconception as described here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Ten_things_you_may_not_know_about_Wikipedia)

Also to make major contributions you need credit as a reputable editor.

[Here is a great description of the bots and volunteers that keep Wiki tidy](http://www.theverge.com/2014/2/18/5412636/this-machine-kills-trolls-how-wikipedia-robots-snuff-out-vandalism)

Also it's a good thing that there is no central authority, it can be influenced, bought, threatened etc.
Things you definitely don't want for something as important as Wikipedia.

PS: please don't use the content-security-policy tag for this question. [This is something entirely unrelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy)